# Google Analytics Tracking -- onclick events

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I want to track my site when the contact us button clicked. 
I added the below code in my js file. and added google tracking code in my footer. 
But nothing has tracked. 
Anyone please guide me how to track the site when button clicks. 
Here is my code.

```
jQuery('.callout-btn').on('click', function(event) {
 ga('send', 'event', {
   eventCategory: 'Phone Number',
   eventAction: 'Call Number Button Clicked',
   eventLabel: event.target.href
 });
});

jQuery('.call-us').on('click', function(event) {
  ga('send', 'event', {
   eventCategory: 'Phone Number',
   eventAction: 'Call Us',
   eventLabel: event.target.href
  });
});

jQuery('.call-now-btn').on('click', function(event) {
  ga('send', 'event', {
   eventCategory: 'Phone Number',
   eventAction: 'Call Us',
   eventLabel: event.target.href
 });
});

jQuery('.ciw_contact_phone').on('click', function(event) {
 ga('send', 'event', {
  eventCategory: 'Phone Number',
  eventAction: 'Number Clicked -Contact Us',
  eventLabel: event.target.href
 });
});

jQuery('.footer-top .ciw_contact_phone').on('click', function(event) {
 ga('send', 'event', {
  eventCategory: 'Phone Number',
  eventAction: 'Number Clicked -Footer'',
  eventLabel: event.target.href
 });
});
```

Thank you!!

Comment: you are using correct format in all events, except the last one (where you have doulble quotes and maybe that breaks your page..? check that out, also you have to wait for events to show in GA like,, one day I think..

Comment: In Analytics you can see live events in real time.

Comment: @KresimirPendic thank you!! I correct the quotes and Check it again.

Comment: I just added one function in my js file and created goal for clicking function. In Real Time i don't see the goal event updation.

Comment: Try to install GA Debug for Chrome and inspect the hit you see (or don't see) to see what might be happening. I'm concerned about your GA code being in the footer, too. You should ideally have that high up on your pages as possible to avoid missing data from people who land on your site and nav to a different page before the page finishes loading.